# Auto fill specific cell range with formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I have this formula:

```
IF(ROWS($Q$27:Q27)<=$P$25,INDEX(DataTable[[#All],[Time]],$P27),"")
```

and if I drag it to the right, it should automatically read each column respectively; example:

```
=IF(ROWS($Q$27:R27)<=$P$25,INDEX(DataTable[[#All],[Name]],$P27),"")
```

^Notice that the first Q27 is fixed, the second Q27 is variable.

I drag this formula to the right by 15 columns, and down to 50 rows. that's 750 formulas in total.

I want to do this in vba, but if I did this, it will be 750 lines of code for each cell representing each row/column.

example: `.Range("G17").Formula=IF(ROWS($Q$27:R27)<=$P$25,INDEX(DataTable[[#All],[Name]],$P27),"""")`

and if I drag it down, it will automatically pick up what I exactly want, example:

```
=IF(ROWS($Q$27:Q28)<=$P$25,INDEX(DataTable[[#All],[Time]],$P28),"")
```

so this formula should be written 750 times in total for the cell range [ A27:N76 ]

Any faster / more dynamic approach? and if possible, can I make it depend on more than 50 lines based on a cell value inside the sheet?

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it all in one line:

```
 Range("A27:N76").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ROWS(R27C17:RC[16])<=R25C16,INDEX((DataTable[[#All],[Name]],RC16),"""")"
```

EDIT: Seems a more that one line of code required after all 
The code below will do what you want (this time fully tested)

```
Sub FillFormulas()

    Dim inC%, rgHead As Range
    
''' Assumes the target sheet is Active.
''' o  If that's not the case, change this With statement to reference the target sheet
With ActiveSheet
    
''' Set rgHead to the Table's header row
    Set rgHead = .ListObjects("DataTable").Range.Rows(1)
    
''' Add the formulas to the target range, column by column updating the table header on the fly
    With .Range("A27:N76")
    
        For inC = 1 To .Columns.Count
            .Columns(inC).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(ROWS(R27C17:RC[16])<=R25C16,INDEX(DataTable[[#All],[" & rgHead.Cells(inC) & "]],RC16),"""")"
        Next inC
    
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Works good but there's only one flaw, as you can see, the formula FIXES this part "INDEX((DataTable[[#All],[Name]]". and it should change across every column like my example above. 
so it should be for column A INDEX((DataTable[[#All],[Name]], column B INDEX((DataTable[[#All],[AnotherName]] column C INDEX((DataTable[[#All],[AnotherAnotherName]], etc. 
excel detects it automatically when I drag across the sheets but does not do it when I write it in a formula, any assistance?
Thank you in advance @Spinner

Comment: To my chagrin (now), I part tested previously (not using table headers as it was quicker. Have now amended with code that simulates exactly what you are doing manually. There's possible a better answer, but this does what you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

*so this formula should be written 750 times in total for the cell range [A27:N76]*

You don't need to do that.  If you specify *range*.Formula, it will fill the proper formulas all the way across and down.  Just give it the formula of the top/left most cell.
So, in your case

```
Range("A27:N76").Formula = "=IF(ROWS($Q$27:R27)<=$P$25 ... "
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: This response had some obvious errors

This has an obvious error (as tested part and then merged to the full thing).

```
Range(A27:N76).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ROWS(R27C17:RC[16])<=R25C16,INDEX((DataTable[[#All],[Name]],$P27),"""")"
```

Comment: You can't mix `R1C1` and `A1` like that

Comment: Hmmm... So you spotted the obvious error. Wouldn't it have been better to edit, rather than just "mark down and comment"? And I ask as I'm new and I always try and help where I can (rather than simply criticize). However, being new, I'm also unclear on what the 'normal' thing to do would be. Is it considered better to take the approach you have, instead?

Comment: The primary purpose of voting (up or down) is to indicate to future readers the usefulness of a post.  A secondary feature is it provides _you_ with feedback, which you can choose to act on, or not, as you see fit.  FWIW, criticism is an essential part of building a useful repository of knowledge

Comment: Sort of makes sense. Have seen others comment and allow time for action before voting stuff up or down. I might stick with that approach, until/if I conclude your approach works best. In the mean time, I've fixed the obvious error (see above). So thanks for pointing it out.